# How can I programmatically access items in a Vector-based Drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

Consider the following vector-based drawable resource...

@drawable/icon_circled_plus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="circledMinus"
    android:width="128dp"
    android:height="128dp"
    android:viewportWidth="128"
    android:viewportHeight="128">

    <path
        android:name="border"
        android:pathData="M 124,64 C 124,97.14 97.14,124 64,124 C 30.86,124 4,97.14 4,64 C 4,44.43 13.37,27.04 27.87,16.09 C 37.92,8.5 50.44,4 64,4 C 97.14,4 124,30.86 124,64 Z"
        android:fillColor="#0000FF"
        android:strokeColor="#0000FF"
        android:strokeWidth="8" />

    <path
        android:name="glyph"
        android:pathData="M 24,71 L 104,71 L 104,57 L 24,57 L 24,71 Z"
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" />

</vector>
```

I know I can use it in my layout files like so:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_circled_plus" />
```

My question is how can I programmatically access the individual elements in the drawable so I can modify them in code?

For instance, 'border' has both a fill and stroke color of blue.  What if I wanted to change them to red based on some application logic?  Can this be done without having to convert this to custom-drawing or creating multiple drawable resources?

Comment: it´s unclear from the documentation, but I don´t think it is possible. Setting a drawable causes the system to convert it into a bitmap, I guess. From `setImageResource()` in the API: `This does Bitmap reading...` so I think a drawable is converted. Via `getDrawable` you get a Drawable from your ImageView, but it seems that there is nowhere a method to convert it back to a vector. But this all is just an asumption because I can´t find a reference to it..

Comment: Actually I think you're both correct.  From further research after posting this, in earlier API versions (I vaguely remember 21 and under) Vectors are converted to bitmaps.  In later APIs, they're rendered as actual VectorDrawables.  And @PSKink, I'm checking out your link, but two things: 1) can you explain it a little better (and if it will work back on API 19), and 2) can you post it as an answer if you think it will work as such?  I can't 'accept' a comment! :)